# Users can authenticate with DRF, but no permissions on POST

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

If i run:

```
curl --user test:incorrectpass -d '{"name":"testplatform"}' -X POST http://localhost:8080/api/v1/platforms
```

I get an error that says invalid credentials (as I should).  If I pass in the correct credentials, this error goes away but I get a "you do not have permission"

The user that I'm authenticating was created from the django admin panel and granted all permissions from the admin panel.  Not sure if there is something else I need to do on the DRF side to enable permissions...

```
class AuthOnPostOnly(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        # only accept POST request with correct token
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.META.get('USERNAME')
            password = request.META.get('PASSWORD')
            if not username and password:
                return None
            try:
                authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('invalid credentials')
        else:
            return True
```

This is a very barebones permission and more of a POC, ultimately I just want to check if user/pass are a match and if so move on, if not, raise an error.

Comment: Do not do authentication in your permission checking...

Answer (score 2):

If request.method is POST you never return anything

```
 try:
    authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    return True
 except User.DoesNotExist:
    raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('invalid credentials')
```

But please don't do authentication here.

Instead add [basic authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#basicauthentication) to your authentication backends.

and then your  permission

```
  ...
 def has_permission(self, request, view):
     if request.method == 'POST':
            return request.user.is_authenticated()
     return True
```